# Ping not working?

Tags: ping, tcp, arp

I read from a book, says that two computer A and B:

A: 192.168.26.129/24 gateway 192.168.26.2

B: 192.168.26.3/27 gateway 192.168.26.2

The book say that if B ping A, it can works.

i.   So I test it on cisco packet tracker, and it's not working?

ii.   But after I change the B to 192.168.26.3/24, and it can work fine, I know that.

iii.   Then I test change B to 192.168.26.3/24, it is still work.

What is the difference between step (i) with setp (iii)?

I know it must relative to arp? someone can tell the detial? or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping IP addressing ranges. 2 possible solutions:

- Preferred: Fix the addressing scheme
- Enable proxy ARP on the router.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how to fix it. My problem is that step (i) and step (iii) comes different result? they are the same

Comment: yeah, when I clear the ARP cache of both computer, I cant ping through. Does this happens in real computer? I only test it on Cisco Packet Tracker. So the book's answer is  not rigorous?

Comment: this happens in real world as well :)